# Django admin hangs (until timeout error) for a specific model when trying to edit/create

Tags: python, django, django-admin

This one is driving me nuts right now. It was not happening before (even got screenshots I had to do for the user-manual since the customer required it).

I first noticed it on production server and then I checked and also happens in the dev server that comes with Django. The model appears on the main-page of the django admin, I can click it and it will display the list of point of sales. The problem comes whenever I want to edit an existing instance or create a new one.

I just click on the link (or put it on the bar) and it just hangs.

```
class PointOfSaleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id','business', 'user', 'zipcode', 'address','date_registered')
    list_filter = ('business',)
    filter_horizontal = ('services',)
admin.site.register(models.PointOfSale, PointOfSaleAdmin)
```

That's the registration of the model. All models are registered in the admin application and the user to test this is a super user. The model is:

```
class PointOfSale(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    zipcode = models.ForeignKey(Zipcode)
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business)
    services = models.ManyToManyField(Service, 
        verbose_name='available services')
    date_registered = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=300)
```

Plus a few methods that shouldn't really matter much. Plus, last time before this that I tested the admin was right after I created all those methods, so it shouldn't matter on this.

The administrator very very rarely has to access this page. Usually it's just listing the PoS, but it still bothers me. Any idea of why it could be hanging? All other models are working just fine.

This is happening on both Django 1.2.5 and 1.3

EDIT:

I modified the timeout limits. It IS working, but somehow it takes several minutes for it to actually happen. So, there is something in the background that is taking ages. I don't understand how come it happens only for this model and it happens in different environments (and with small datasets)

---

I almost feel like slapping myself. My fault for not sleeping for so long.

The problem is that the zipcode list is pretty big (dozens of thousands) and the foreign key field is loaded as an html select tag, which means it loads every single entry. It's an issue with how much data there is simply.

Now I wonder how to control the way the foreign key is displayed in the admin. Anyone could help with that?

Comment: Interesting question with an interesting answer. I've been guilty of this within the last month - test your application with large datasets, because tracking down issues like this is non-obvious when you believe you've tested everything.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In your admin.py file, under the appropriate admin class, set

```
raw_id_fields = ('zipcode',)
```

This will display the zipcode's PK instead of a dropdown.

Is there a reason that you are setting up zipcode as it's own model instead of using a CharField or an actual zipcode [modelfield](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/localflavor/)?

Comment: I've never used those to be honest. Although the reason I'm using zipcode as a model is because I got all the coordinates (longitudes and latitudes) and I'm using it to display (in a GMap) where the points of sales are located across the USA. Thank you!

Comment: Fair enough. Just wanted to make sure there wasn't have been a better solution.

Comment: BTW, I eventually ended up using something from django_extension that provides autocomplete to the admin. Awful documentation and it didn't do exactly what I wanted, but I modified a lot of the code and made it behave right.

Comment: I had a similar issue and this worked for me. I just wish Django was smart enough to not try to render a drop-down with 100,000+ items...

Answer (score 10):

I just wanted to add that another option here is creating a `read_only_fields` list. In cases where there is a relationship to a model with a large number of choices(in my case a rel table cataloging flags between a large number of users and discussion threads) but you don't need to edit the field. You can add it to the `read_only_fields` list will just print the value rather than the choices.

```
class FlaggedCommentsAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('user', 'discussion', 'flagged_on')
    readonly_fields = ('user', 'discussion')
```

Answer (score 6):

For people still landing on this page: As Mamsaac points out in his original post, the timeout happens because django tries to load all instances of a `ForeignKey` into an html-select. Django 2 lets you add an [auto-complete field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.autocomplete_fields) which asynchronously lets you search for the `ForeignKey` to deal with this. In your `admin.py` do something like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Parent, Child

@admin.register(Parent)
class ParentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # tell admin to autocomplete-select the "Parent"-field 'children'
    autocomplete_fields = ['children']

@admin.register(Child)
class ChildAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # when using an autocomplete to find a child, search in the field 'name'
    search_fields = ['name']
```

Comment: *autocomplete_fields = ['children']* did the trick to me

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking the apache logs (if you're using apache obviously) or any other HTTP server related logs? That might give you an idea of where to start.

That's the only model that is affected? You mentioned methods on the model. Try commenting out those methods and trying again (including the `__unicode__` method), just to see if they somehow affect it. Reduce everything down to the bare minimum (as much as possible obviously), to try and deduce where the regression started.

Try to monitor server resources when you request this page. Does CPU spike dramatically? What about network I/O? Could be a database issue (somehow?).

Sorry this doesn't really answer your question, but those are the first debugging techniques that I'd attempt trying to diagnose the problem.

Comment: I checked the logs. I'm using Apache/WSGI. There's no errors except for some deprecationwarnings (but those are coming from Django and I verified it's not related to this issue). I took ALL of the Admin attributes in all models (notice, this in admin.py file) and tried again with no success. So, I'm considering it could be in models.py, but I haven't found anything suspicious :( No CPU spikes, I did check. I think it must be a DB issue somehow, indeed :S And thanks a lot! I will check more on the db

Comment: I don't remember doing so, but if I changed the models without manually altering the table structure, could that be the souce?