# Is it possible to disable the generation of related objects when deleting an object via Django admin?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I'm currently maintaining a legacy system while a new system is brought up. I noticed recently that I get a timeout when trying to delete certain objects from a specific model. I've tracked this down to being related to the following question which has an accepted answer: [Django admin hangs (until timeout error) for a specific model when trying to edit/create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5848319/django-admin-hangs-until-timeout-error-for-a-specific-model-when-trying-to-edi)

The problem I'm having is that the objects that are related are not directly related from my model in question.

For example I have the following models (generically named to remain vague due to IP at my company):

- `ModelA` which is the model I'm seeing the issue with when deleting from the Django Admin site
- `ModelB` which contains a ForeignKey field to `ModelA`
- `ModelC` which contains a ForeignKey field to `ModelB`
- `ModelD` which contains a ForeignKey field to `ModelC`
- `ModelE` which contains a ForeignKey field to `ModelD`

Model details:

- `ModelE` can contain tens/hundreds/thousands of entries for any entry of
- `ModelC`. Additionally `ModelC` can contain tens/hundreds/thousands of entries for any entry of `ModelB`

Currently when I try to delete `ModelA` Django attempts to generate all the associated objects all the way down to `ModelE` which is causing a timeout in certain cases with high number of associated `ModelC` and `ModelE`.

Is there a way to avoid this either by overriding a custom template such as delete_confirmation_template or through any other method? Ideally I would like to still show the summary, but I'm not sure that will be possible with the nature of this issue.

A few details for context:

- I feel this may be due to a poor overall structure in our DB Schema, but like I mentioned earlier this is a Legacy system.
- I do not need an immediate fix for this as I will actually never delete entries for this model except for my current scenario/task of cleaning up duplicated entries(user error not controlled correctly by forms; The forms now check for this) which is being done through a migration script. I simply noticed this when trying to clean up things and leverage this intermediate page as a sanity check when testing said migration script

[Timeout screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hv9qQ.png)

Comment: Which version of Django? What's the `on_delete` value of the various `ForeignKey` fields? Are you implying that `on_delete` is set to `CASCADE` and therefore the admin is trying to show all the related models that will also be deleted?

Comment: Django version 1.11 and yes in almost all cases it is set to CASCADE

Comment: First, I would ask myself whether `CASCADE` is the correct behaviour (often with Django version < 2.x, developers just didn't think about the appropriate settings, so it defaulted to `CASCADE`). Maybe you want it to be `SET_NULL`, which would fix your issue. Second, if `CASCADE` is the correct behaviour, then there's not much you can do except changing the timeout settings: the fact that all the related models need to be fetched isn't just due to the displaying of the confirmation template, it will happen anyway when the actual `delete()` operation happens.

Comment: @dirkgroten I have been thinking about that myself. With the nature of the data and the models I think it would be more appropriate for the on_delete to be `SET_NULL` in many cases. Specifically, for the `ModelC` and on, these should never be deleted as they are test results for an automated system and should always be preserved. Furthermore, `ModelA` should probably never be deleted either. I think for my current case I will simply disable the delete ability from the admin site (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043843/in-django-admin-how-do-i-disable-the-delete-link)

Comment: you can set `has_delete_permission()` on your `ModelAdmin` class to return `False` (or check the user's role, e.g. return `True` only for `is_superuser`), see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.has_delete_permission)

Comment: @dirkgroten Thank you for your comments. They were very helpful. I went with a modified version of your suggestion for using `SET_NULL`. In my case while `CASCADE` is not appropriate, `PROTECT` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From discussions in the comments I came to the following conclusion(s):

- `on_delete` being set to `CASCADE` for models was incorrect and was causing the very high times in retrieving related objects when attempting to delete a model
- Since I do not want to allow deleting of these objects when other specific models have associations to them I analyzed and appropriately set `on_delete` to `PROTECT` where applicable
- Now when I attempt to delete an object it will not allow me to delete the object due to protected related items. It also resolves the timeout issue I was previously observing

This allows me to still delete objects from this model via the Django admin site IF they have no related protected objects, which in the end is the functionality I desire